# A verb phrase "[verb] up" meaning someone is easily buying whatever he sees on TV

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I came across this phrase "[verb] up" twice on The Guardian Reader's comments section when readers were talking about someone tends to not raise much objection to whatever the person is told or believes whatever crap showing on TV. Readers there used the verb phrase to describe such people. I tried very hard for two days to recall what exactly the verb was but to no avail. Any idea what this verb phrase might be? Thanks.

Comment: "clam up" maybe? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clam%20up This expression is often used to mean "refuse to reply to (unwanted) questions." If the phrase you're asking about was used as a verb, this might fit. If it's being used as a predicate noun ("So and so is a [verb]-up"), then "clam up" would *not* fit in that context.

Comment: The first part of your description "tends not to raise much objection" made me think of the phrase above, but the second part "believes whatever..." seems more like it's describing a quality than an action. The standard word for this is "gullible," so maybe search for synonyms/idioms with the same meaning as the word "gullible"?